# How to avoid duplicate Title, H1 tags on keyword pages?

Tags: duplicate-content, title, pagination

As my question states i want to avoid duplicate Title and H1 tags on my website.

My pages are like this

```
example.com/rock-music-list-1/
...
example.com/rock-music-list-9/
```

On each page there is a pagination system that allow users to go back and forth.

```
 [<] [1] [2] ... [8] [9] [>]
```

So on each of these 9 pages they all have the exact title and h1 tag.

Comment: What's wrong with `<h1>Rock Mustic List 1</h1>`, `<h1>Rock Music List 2</h1>`? if you don't know how to make those changes then your question would be better of on Stack Overflow with the code you already have or if Joomla/WordPress on there stack....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicates like these are a thing of the past if you have set up proper schemas/relations/canonicals in regards to pagination: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663744?hl=en

Note this too from the bottom of that article:

> rel="next" and rel="prev" are orthogonal concepts to rel="canonical".

This means that each page is it's own canonical, which is contrary to the popular practice of making only the *first* page the canonical. In the snippet on the Google KB page we see this example of this:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/article?story=abc&page=2"/>
<link rel="prev" href="http://www.example.com/article?story=abc&page=1&sessionid=123" />
<link rel="next" href="http://www.example.com/article?story=abc&page=3&sessionid=123" />
```

Notice how page 2 is a canonical. When you goto page 3, that would be a canonical. All pages are a canonical in relation to others before and/or after them.

Some other things you can do is to dynamically add `- Page 3` to the ends of page titles beyond page 1. Or you can also indicate via SERP that youre about to land into page 3 (for example) by putting the pagination current location info in a syntax that looks specifically like this:

`Showing 30-40 of 100` or `Products 30-40 of 100`

Which will show in SERPS like this:

[image: generic pagination]
[image: product pagination]

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with dhaupin, it is an issue that is every common with blog pagination and few SEO plugins, themes, templates make it right.

The first page should contain

```
<link rel="next" href="url-to-page-2">
```

The second page and following pages should contain:

```
<link rel="previous" href="url-to-page-1">
<link rel="next" href="url-to-page-3">
```

The last page should contain:

```
<link rel="previous" href="url-to-page-x">
```

None of the inner pages should have a canonical tag to the first page but they should always point to their own url

**Reference:**
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663744?hl=en
[http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.fr/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html)
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.fr/2013/04/5-common-mistakes-with-relcanonical.html

Comment: Actually the inner pages should all have canonicals. Its a misconception that canonical can/should only be first page (probably due to lack of info initially from google). Check that link you shared, at the bottom, there is `rel="next" and rel="prev" are orthogonal concepts to rel="canonical".`. Now when we see the def of "orthogonal" it means a point of reference, like the corner of a right angle. In their example, page 2 is orthogonal to page 1 and 3, therefore they call page 2 a canonical: `<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/article?story=abc&page=2"/>`

Answer (score 0):

For paginated page or other variations, you can put canonical tag to parent page.

This will solve problem.

For example:

```
example.com/rock-music-list-1/
example.com/rock-music-list-2/
example.com/rock-music-list-3/
example.com/rock-music-list-4/
```

all with canonical `example.com/rock-music-list`